# How to fetch data of a a vertex or an edge from JanusGraph using its Java driver?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I'm connecting to a remote JanusGraph server. There is no problem with the connection but I can't understand the Java API.

I'm running a Java Spring HTTP server. Inside the HTTP response method, I'm creating a graph traversal source like

`GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");`

It seems fine. But When I want to get data about a Vertex I can not with the below code.

`g.V(28712).next().keys()`

**IT GIVES AN EMPTY RESPONSE! WHY?**

If I do the same with gremlin shell, I see it. See the below picture

[image]

If I do `g.V(28712).valueMap(true).unfold().toList();` in Java, I see some results.

[image]

I just want to fetch data for a vertex or edge with Java. How should I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you connect to a Gremlin Server using one of the Gremlin clients and you ask for a vertex, what you get back is a reference vertex. A reference vertex just contains the ID and the label. To get some properties you need to include them using `valueMap`, `elementMap`, `project` etc. Alternatively you can configure the Gremlin Server to return all properties. The default is set this way to reduce the amount of data that gets sent back to a client.

Please see the documentation for further details.

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-applications

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_properties_of_elements

There is a link in that documentation to a post about why the decisions were made. For convenience, I am including that link here as well.

https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e959e85d4f8b3d46d281f2742a6e574c7d27c54bfc52f802f7c04af3%40%3Cdev.tinkerpop.apache.org%3E